# Prevent property value inspect when exception is thrown

Tags: ruby

When an exception in thrown for a ruby object, the object's properties are serialized into the exception message.

```rb
class MyClass
  def initialize
    @hash = {
      user: 'user_name',
      password: 'value_that_should_not_be_dumped'
    }
  end
end

begin
  MyClass.new.foo
rescue StandardError => e 
  puts e.message
end
```

Sample Output

```
bash-4.2$ bundle exec ruby exc.rb
undefined method `foo' for #<MyClass:0x00007feae939b378 @hash={:user=>"user_name", :password=>"value_that_should_not_be_dumped"}>
```

I am able to prevent this if I override the `Object.inspect` method.

```rb
class Object
  def inspect
    "#{self.class} (values suppressed)"
  end
end
```

Sample Output

```
bash-4.2$ bundle exec ruby exc.rb
undefined method `foo' for MyClass (values suppressed):MyClass
```

Ideally, I would like to indicate whether or not StandardError should invoke `inspect` on the object in question.  Alternatively, I would like to be able to mark specific properties for exclusion from the inspect operation.

Is there a good way to accomplish this in ruby?

Comment: You can override `inspect` on your specific class. Overriding it on `Object` seems extremely rude.

Comment: You could make an inspect suppression mixin. This makes it easy to snipe classes to suppress.

Comment: Are you only worried about exceptions or about inspecting objects in general?

Comment: I am primarily worried about exceptions since I want to log the contents of exception.message

Comment: Someone had commented here to consider a Ruby "refinement".  The comment has since disappeared.  That might provide a good way for me to limit the override of the inspect method just to my logging class...

Comment: That was me but I wanted to clarify the use case first. For passwords, it would be best to not store them as plaintext inside the object in the first place.